# how do i resolve this bad record length error

Tags: vb.net, file-handling

I keep getting a bad record length error when i try to save the record to a file.
can anyone give me any suggestions? Look at the Code snippet.
also i need to use this method as its for class.
thanks
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK1uE.png)

```
    Dim output As String
    'Old Delete Block
    If File.Exists(fileName) = True Then
        File.Delete(fileName)
        Debug.WriteLine("file deleted ")
    End If
    'Using fs As FileStream = File.Create(fileName)
    '    For Each t In coastalTowns
    '        output = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(String.Format(myFormat, t.name, t.county, t.population, t.area))
    '        fs.Write(output, 0, output.Length)
    '    Next
    'End Using
    FileOpen(2, fileName, OpenMode.Random, , , 43)
    Debug.WriteLine(Len(town))
    While EOF(2)
        For Each T In coastalTowns
            If Not T.name = "" Then
                output = (String.Format(myFormat, T.name, T.county, T.population, T.area))
                FilePut(2, output)
            End If

        Next

    End While
```

I do understand that this is an obsolete was of writing to a file but the data file we were given for class needs to use this method. 
here is the Structure and myFormat declarations

```
Structure TownType
    <VBFixedString(20)> Dim name As String
    <VBFixedString(15)> Dim county As String
    Dim population As Integer
    Dim area As Integer
End Structure
Dim town As TownType
Dim myFormat As String = "{0, -20}{1,-20}{2,-10}{3,-10}"
```

This the error i keep getting and i have read the  [FilePut documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s9sa1ab(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
    System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Bad record length.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FilePut(Int32 FileNumber, String Value, Int64 RecordNumber, Boolean StringIsFixedLength)
       at task_1.Module1.saveFile() in J:\AS Comp Linear\Pract\VB.Net\Sect 2 Prog Tasks NT Bk\Section 2 - Prog\2.7 Text files and files of records\task 1\2.7-Task_2\task 1\Module1.vb:line 83
       at task_1.Module1.Main() in J:\AS Comp Linear\Pract\VB.Net\Sect 2 Prog Tasks NT Bk\Section 2 - Prog\2.7 Text files and files of records\task 1\2.7-Task_2\task 1\Module1.vb:line 116
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We need the code in the question for this to ever be relevant to anyone else ever.  Besides which it is in your interest to make it easy for people to help you by not hiding The Important part of your question in another castle

Comment: a) when you trying to use those old File functions, VS pops up some help telling you that there are much better NET methods now.  Consider heeding the advice b) since you are just writing text why random access?  c) you didnt tell where **where** the error is, but when it dies, hold the mouse over `output` and my crystal ball says it will not be the length you defined (43?)

Comment: It would help if you documented the town class and what myFormat looks like.  I haven't seen code like that since the 1990's.  You probably don't need that old school FileOpen and FilePut, etc.  Try opening a StreamWriter and use the WriteLine method.

Comment: The `FileOpen/Len/EOF/FilePut` methods are old and exists purely for backwards compatibility. I suggest you start learning how to use the native .NET methods instead. For this situation I recommend using a [**`StreamWriter`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As you may have seen i have used the native .NET methods.  to make sure my program flow would work. but i can not use this method as my teacher want us to use FileOpen.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: [FilePut Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s9sa1ab(v=vs.90).aspx).  Remark section, point #2 under Random Mode: `If the variable being written is a string, FilePut writes a two-byte descriptor containing the string length, and then writes the data that goes into the variable. Therefore, the record length specified by the RecordLength clause in the FileOpen function must be at least two bytes greater than the actual length of the string.`

Comment: Its really sad that any institution, at any level, anywhere is still teaching VB6 style File ops nearly 15 years after VB.NET 2003 was released

Comment: It's not the language that matters it's the programming skills that we need to learn for the exam. The ability to read and understand the code regardless of the language.

Comment: You have to turn the clock back to an era before you were born.  Back when Basic ran on 16-bit operating systems.  And an Integer took 2 bytes, not 4.  So the record length is wrong, it is 39, not 43.  I think, been too long.